# Stream API grouping

Tags: java, java-stream

To group and calculate the sum, I use the construction

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<SomeClass> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(new SomeClass("Someone", 3, 2));
        list.add(new SomeClass("AnotherOne", 4, 6));
        list.add(new SomeClass("Someone", 1, 4));

        Map<String, Integer> someones = list.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.toMap
                        e -> e.name, 
                        e -> e.field1 + e.field2,
                        Integer::sum,
                        LinkedHashMap::new));

        System.out.println(someones); // {Someone=10, AnotherOne=10}
    }
}
public class SomeClass {
    String name;
    int field1;
    int field2;

    public SomeClass(String name, int field1, int field2) {
        this.name = name;
        this.field1 = field1;
        this.field2 = field2;
    }
}
```

how can I bring the answer to the form `[SomeClass ("Someone", field1 = 4, field2 = 6), SomeClass ("AnotherOne", field1 = 4, field2 = 6)]`, that is, sum `field1` and `field1` with a common name to group by `name` and output to `List`

Comment: `e -> e` (or `Function.identity()`) for the value extractor, `(e1, e2) -> new SomeClass(e1.name, e1.field1 + e2.field1, e1.field2 + e2.field2)` for the merger. Is that what you're looking for? That will give you a `Map<String, SomeClass>`.

Comment: it helped, thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

Try Collectors.groupingBy

```
        Map<String, Integer> collect = list.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(SomeClass::getName, 
                    Collectors.summingInt(e -> e.getField1() + e.getField2())));
```

Comment: and how would this result in the desired output mentioned in the question?